# Long INSERT on large table blocks INSERT on other tables

Tags: insert, mysql-5.7, blocking

Server is MySQL 5.7 and the tables are InnoDB. The large table consists of 20+ GB of data. The large table has several indexes on it and also full_text_indexes!

Use-Case explained:

There are multiple long INSERT with each of 250 "VALUES()" rows. While those are executed, the server starts to delay other tiny INSERTs on other tables.

There is no obvious technical (no ON INSERT, TRIGGER or similar) or logical connection between the large table and the others. When inserting something into the large table it should not have an impact on other inserts, at least this is the goal ...

Is there something I can check/set to make requests on those other tables not waiting for the INSERT on this large table to be finished?

Comment: What do you mean "delay" tiny inserts? My first thought is that your large query is using a ton of memory and disk resources. I would check the files to start, do the tables that you are inserting into that are receiving more wait time than typical reside on the same disk as the other large table? What about the log files? Did you limit how much memory MySQL can use on the server? Did you limit how much memory MySQL can use on a query?